# In Meteor Method, why is this.connection.clientAddress undefined?

Tags: javascript, meteor

```
// on server
Meteor.methods({
  'getIP': function () {
    return this.connection.clientAddress;
  }
});

// on client
Meteor.startup(function() {
  Meteor.call('getIP', function (err, res) {
    console.log(res);  // returns undefined
  });
});
```

digging further, it seems 'this.connection' on the server only has 3 things: id, close, onClose, but not clientAddress.  What am I missing?

Additional info:

- Running [vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) on windows host with
  ubuntu remote.
- I tried setting the environment variable HTTP_FORWARDED_COUNT to 0,
  1, and 2 but no luck.
- doc reference: http://docs.meteor.com/#publish_connection

Comment: Hmm.. try putting `console.log(self.socket.headers["x-forwarded-for"])` in `/path/to/meteor/packages/livedata/livedata_server.js` in the `_clientAddress` function, (approx line 811)

Comment: I tried something different.  I am using iron-router and I made a server-side route and did two things: `console.log(this.request.connection.remoteAddress);` and `console.log(this.request.headers);`  The first gives 127.0.0.1 and the second gives the headers including 'x-forwarded-for': '10.0.2.2' but I'm not sure what to make of that...

Comment: is that with `HTTP_FORWARDED_COUNT`=1?

Comment: I just tried it with `HTTP_FORWARDED_COUNT` unset, explicit 0, 1, and 2.. all gave the same result

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Meteor 0.9.3.1 and calling `this.connection.clientAddress` inside a Meteor method is working for me. I store the client IP address as a field in a Collection set I'm working with.

I did have one problem, the client was trying to simulate the call and was throwing the `Exception while simulating the effect of invoking... this.connection is undefined` error. But I noticed my documents were getting stored correctly with the correct client IP address.  So the fix is to just not have the client try to simulate this.

In my Meteor method I just added a `Meteor.isServer` check. It shouldn't matter if the client simulates the client IP being `0.0.0.0`:

```
var ip = "0.0.0.0";

if(Meteor.isServer) {
    if(!this.connection.clientAddress)
       throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Server Error: You must be connected.");
    else
       ip = this.connection.clientAddress;
}

//  ...store document with ip...
```

And everything works as intended.

Comment: A more explicit solution could simply check if the call is being made from a method simulation or not: `if (!this.isSimulation) { ip = this.connection.clientAddress; }`